# HTML 5 video and src value with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an HTML 5 video inside my page and I would like to set the src dynamically.
I'm using vue, inside my js controller I set a variable with the video path then I use the variable in my page as below:

```
<video width="450" controls>
    <source v-model="controller.var" v-bind:src="var" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The player doesn't load the video but my var is properly set with the right url.
What I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include your vue code? It seems to be working in this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRogVw

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, I don't know if you are actually using `var` in your template, but if you are, Vue will throw a warning in the template.

> - avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "var" in expression :src="var"

Second, you cannot dynamically change the source element.

From the HTML5 [specification](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-source-element),

> Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the
>   element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no
>   effect. To change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the
>   media element directly, possibly making use of the canPlayType()
>   method to pick from amongst available resources. Generally,
>   manipulating source elements manually after the document has been
>   parsed is an unnecessarily complicated approach.

So, bind your data to the `src` attribute of the `video` element.

```
<video width="450" controls :src="video"></video>
```

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    video: "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"
  },
  methods:{
    changeVideo(){
      this.video = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <video width="450" controls :src="video"></video>
  <div>
    <button @click="changeVideo">Change</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It solved the issue; binding the src attribute of the video element works fine. Tnx.

Comment: this method actually did not work for me when i tried previously. in the iOS simulator I did have luck using `v-if` on the `<source>` tags in the video tag, checking a variable stored in vuex. It does not work in chrome on desktop however :(

Answer (score 48):

Adding the [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) attribute with the source's URL to the *video* element will cause both video and source to be updated when the URL changes:

```html
<template>
  <video
    :key="src"
    :width="width"
    controls
  >
    <source
      :src="src"
      :type="type"
    >
  </video>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        src: 'https://www.example.org/video.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        width: 450
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This supports dynamic replacement of a video + source.

Comment: I didn't try other solutions but this one works very well and looks conceptually more correct than changing the syntax of the video tag, especially in a context in which we may want to support different video formats.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to change the `src` dynamically, you can change the `src` and load the new src with the `.load()` function.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    src: ""
  },
  methods:{
    changeVideo(newSrc){
      this.$data.src = newSrc;
      //Force video load.
      var vid = this.$refs.video;
      vid.load();

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <video width="450" controls :src="src" ref="video"></video>
  <div>
    <button @click="changeVideo('http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4')">Change1</button>
        <button @click="changeVideo('https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4')">Change2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the entire `source` as variable in the controller.

```
<video controls autoplay>
  {{{ src }}}
</video>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    src: '<source src="#url" type="video/mp4">'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be interested, here is another equally elegant solution

```
<source v-if="src" :src="src" :type="type">
```

from https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2876#issuecomment-278579297